# In ASP.NET, After Selecting "Stay On This Page" nothing is working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I am using this code for preventing user to leave the page if there is any changes on the form in SharePoint FarmApplication

```
 <script>
    var formDirty = false;
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {

      if (formDirty) {
            return "You have unsaved changes on the page";
        }
    };
</script>
```

But, after user select "stay on this page", nothing is working like Buttons or DropDowns.
Actually the form can not post anything to server.

What is going wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this script even fired. Also [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103544/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101304-1.aspx) is a good guide with examples about asp.Net form dirty confirmations.

```
<script>
    var formDirty = false;
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        var confirmMsg = undefined;
        if (formDirty) {
            confirmMsg = "You have unsaved changes on the page";
        }
        return confirmMessage;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: It did not make any changes. Also, your link does not help me. Actually, I have created an empty asp.net web project without with Master page. this code is working properly. I do not know why inside the SharePoint project. I have this problem

Comment: @HedayatAbedijoo you don't mention sharepoint in your question.